# South - migrating Django application from sqlite to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, django, sqlite, python-3.x, django-south

While waiting for a MSSQL backend compatible with Django 1.6, I've been doing development using SQLite and using South to keep my models synced with the DB.

Now that django-mssql v. 1.5 (which supports Django 1.6) is available, I'd like to move my Django models to a SQL Server database. Note that there is only test data in my SQLite database, so there's no need to migrate the data - I'm only interested in implementing the models in SQL Server, and using South to implement schema modifications going forward.

I think the proper procedure after installing django-mssql is:

1. Change the settings.py to point to the MSSQL database per the
   django-mssql installation instructions
2. Remove all of the existing South migrations and the migrations
   folder
3. Run `manage.py syncdb`
4. Run `manage.py schemamigration --initial <application_name>`
5. Run `manage.py migrate <application_name>`

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Note that you don't have to remove all existing migration files. That's the beauty of south. You'd just have to do `python manage.py syncdb; python manage.py migrate` once you change your settings to use the MSSQL db

Comment: If you do choose to remove all existing migrations, then your first syncdb command will create the schema based on your current models. Calling `schemamigration --initial` will create a migration that tries to create those tables again. So you need to add the `--fake` flag on `migrate`

Comment: @SohanJain - thanks - I'll try to just move to SQL Server and keep my migrations intact. I can't hurt anything at this point. I was hoping to come back and add my steps and their results, but the django-mssql installation is throwing an error and failing, so I need to resolve that before I can do anything